# Preserving metadata in resized image using PHP

Tags: php, metadata, image-resizing

I have a PHP script which scans a directory for images, resizes any it finds and saves them back overwriting the originals.
It works well except for the fact that it strips the metadata from the image.

I found a Toolkit which can manipulate Metadata including extracting and writing it to images.
On [this page](http://ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/library/documentation/example.html) it explains how to do this (at the bottom of the page).

So I added it to my code but am having problems - it does not write the metadata to the resized image.
I am obviously missing something but can't seem to figure out what (probably my lack of coding skill) and wondered if someone can spot my error and suggest a correction.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

This is used just to confirm what images are found and do contain metadata - by printing it in an html format

```
echo " $file <br> " ;
        $filename = $file;
        $exif_data = get_EXIF_JPEG( $filename );
        echo Interpret_EXIF_to_HTML( get_EXIF_JPEG( $filename ), $filename );
```

Here is the code which then resizes the image and saves it, and should write the meatada to it - but doesn't

```
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
        ImageCopyResized($new_image, $tmp_image,0,0,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
        //Grab new image
        imagejpeg($new_image, $target_path);
        $image_buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ImageDestroy($new_image);
        ImageDestroy($tmp_image);
        echo " $file resized to $new_width x $new_height <br> \n";
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";
        $jpeg_header_data = put_EXIF_JPEG( $exif_data, $jpeg_header_data );
        put_jpeg_header_data( $filename, $filename, $jpeg_header_data ); 
        ob_flush();
        flush();
```

Is this a case of having put the rewrite code in the wrong place - or something else?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you missing some code ? I don't see where you create/initialize variable '$exif_data'

Comment: bart, the first part of the code contains the create part for the $exif_data - just before it prints it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here :

> put_jpeg_header_data( $filename, $filename, $jpeg_header_data );

changed to

> put_jpeg_header_data( $filename, $new/OUTPUT_image, $jpeg_header_data );

Hope it works!

Comment: AB -  The original code on the site referred to had [put_jpeg_header_data( $filename, 'output.jpg', $jpeg_header_data );]. But this did not work either as no 'output.jpg' was created. AND what I want to do is to resize the original image with the same name and then add back the metadata. That's why I used $filename twice.